# Unable to log into 20.04 -- How do I fix Fbcon?

Tags: login, lightdm, gdm

Noob here.

I messed something up when I tried to install Linux Homebrew and now I'm unable to log into my main desktop (I get kicked out when I correctly enter my credentials). I've since uninstalled that software and tried a number of fixes that I'll list here with some other relevant (I hope) info

**Current operating system:**

Linux 5.4.0-40-generic #44 Ubuntu SMP x86_64

**Graphics card**

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)

**Troubleshooting I've tried:**

- Followed the top answer on this stack exchange: [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)
- Installed libpam-kwallet4 and libpam-kwallet5 which fixed errors appearing in my log files but ultimately seemed to be a red herring
- installed libpam-winbind
- disabled quiet-splash in GRUB
- enabled nomodeset
- reinstalled xorg
- Updated Ubuntu from 19.10 to 20.04

One error in particular that stuck out to me (I've since forgotten how I got it... maybe from startx?) was the following:

`FATAL: Module fbcon not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-genericintel`

Which looks scary and so is probably relevant

Here are some other errors in the Xorg.0 logfile I haven't been able to make sense of yet:

```
EE: Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section
EE: Open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
EE: No devices detected
EE: Systemd-logind: failed to get session: PID 967 does not belong to any known session
```

Finally, here's a snippet from my auth.log file at an instance where I was trying to log in.

```
Jul 20 15:54:28 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA sudo:   name : TTY=tty4 ; PWD=/home/name ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl restart gdm
Jul 20 15:54:28 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by name(uid=0)
Jul 20 15:54:38 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jul 20 15:54:38 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm by LOGIN(uid=0)
Jul 20 15:54:38 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA systemd-logind[941]: New session c6 of user gdm.
Jul 20 15:54:38 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Jul 20 15:54:38 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA gnome-keyring-daemon[12333]: couldn't access control socket: /run/user/121/keyring/control: No such file or directory
Jul 20 15:54:38 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA gnome-keyring-daemon[12337]: couldn't access control socket: /run/user/121/keyring/control: No such file or directory
Jul 20 15:54:38 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA gnome-keyring-daemon[12337]: couldn't access control socket: /run/user/121/keyring/control: No such file or directory
Jul 20 15:54:39 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed for user gdm
Jul 20 15:54:39 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA systemd-logind[941]: Session c6 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Jul 20 15:54:39 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA systemd-logind[941]: Removed session c6.
Jul 20 15:54:39 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm by LOGIN(uid=0)
Jul 20 15:54:39 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA systemd-logind[941]: New session c7 of user gdm.
Jul 20 15:54:43 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA gnome-keyring-daemon[12560]: couldn't access control socket: /run/user/121/keyring/control: No such file or directory
Jul 20 15:54:43 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA gnome-keyring-daemon[12563]: couldn't access control socket: /run/user/121/keyring/control: No such file or directory
Jul 20 15:54:43 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA gnome-keyring-daemon[12563]: couldn't access control socket: /run/user/121/keyring/control: No such file or directory
Jul 20 15:54:44 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c7 (system bus name :1.138 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authe>
Jul 20 15:54:47 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul 20 15:54:53 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul 20 15:54:53 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Jul 20 15:54:53 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA gdm-password]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
Jul 20 15:54:53 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user name by (uid=0)
Jul 20 15:54:53 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA systemd-logind[941]: New session 7 of user name.
Jul 20 15:54:53 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA gdm-password]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly and unlocked keyring
Jul 20 15:54:58 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session closed for user name
Jul 20 15:54:58 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA systemd-logind[941]: Session 7 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Jul 20 15:54:58 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA systemd-logind[941]: Removed session 7.
Jul 20 15:55:06 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA login[13942]: pam_unix(login:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul 20 15:55:10 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA login[13942]: pam_unix(login:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul 20 15:55:10 Virgil-ZenBook-UX431FA login[13942]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user name by LOGIN(uid=0)
```

Might also be worth mentioning that I'm working from a remote desktop right now (ctrl + alt + f4 -> startx) and there are some applications I have that refuse to start. Not sure if that's relevant. Please let me know if there's any other info I can provide.